# Terminate worker thread which is running message loop in C#

Tags: c#, .net, windows, winforms

I have used the `SetWindowHookEx()` Windows API in a worker thread and to receive the OS notifications I have run Application Message Pump by using `Application.Run()`.

Now, I want to stop the message pump and quit the worker thread, but I have no good way to terminate the thread.

Alternatively, I am using `Thread.Abort()` method to terminate the thread, but this is not recommended method to terminate the thread gracefully.

Can anyone please suggest how to gracefully close message pump from UI thread or Main Form, so that the worker thread automatically returns and quits?

Comment: Could you use BackgroundWorker with SupportsCancellation?

Comment: If you are .NET4 based, I would suggest looking at the Task object in System.Threading.Tasks.  It has a cancellation token which you can use to abort the operation.

Comment: Is your application running two message pumps at the same time?  If so...that's probably bad.  You should try to avoid doing that in the first place and re-use a single pump.

Comment: Thread.Abort() is no longer the horrible bit of "£@$ it used to be. Rather than stopping something dead, it now raises an exception which can be used to gracefully release any locks and resources as necessary

Answer (score 4):

Rather than using the parameterless `Application.Run` use the overload that accepts an `ApplicationContext`.

The application context has an `ExitThread` method that will gracefully end the message loop.

Comment: Seems I answered in a reversed way?

Answer (score 0):

Why not just call Application.Exit from another thread?

Answer (score -2):

if you gracefully handle the ThreadAbortException that Thread.Abort() will cause in the worker thread, there is nothing ungraceful about aborting the thread.

Comment: This is just wrong.  When you're aborting arbitrary methods lots of *very* bad things can happen, ranging from leaving unmanaged resources uncleaned up, not actually aborting if the code you're calling is trapping all exceptions while in a long loop, etc.  If you're only aborting a thread running a fixed set of code you have looked through you can be sure none of that will happen, but that's not the case here, as basically anything could be put in that message pump.